# Android How to specity 9patch corner radius in dp?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use 9patch on Android app,
overall screen layout is in dp unit so the 9-patch UI parts' size(Like button width) also.

It seems like that when building UI in dp unit, only a 9-patch corner size should be defined in pixel unit (means I cannot specify corner parts' size at all - the original pixel is used) and it's difficult to control the corner radius of that 9patch.

Is there a way to define a corner radius of a 9patch in dp unit or good workaround to control the corner size of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nine-patch drawables do not have a corner radius. You control how they are stretched [via the rules embedded in the 1px wide border](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Comment: Do you mean the corner size of a Nine-patch can only be controlled by how much "pixel" does the corner take? i think it's very annoying while the stretchable area can be set by dp unit :(

Comment: "Do you mean the corner size of a Nine-patch can only be controlled by how much "pixel" does the corner take?" -- there is no concept of "corner size" with most drawables.